# Maximo - Import the Include/Exclude Fields file into Object Structure

Tags: database, maximo

I have downloaded the include exclude/fields file from the object structure.
This contains the field name and a YorN value for if you include the field or not.

I am wondering if anyone knows of a guide, or if someone can guide me (if it's even possible) on how to import that file back into the object structure.

If this is not possible, is there a quicker way to update the include/exclude fields in the object structure, as there are over 500 fields to go through?

Comment: Hi Kren, Did you sort this out or not?